# Apple Pay not working on release build (works on debug)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, applepay

I got apple pay set up on my app, and everything was working great when I tested locally. I was able to put through real payments on a real device. Then, I pushed to the app store and it's no longer working.

I was able to repro locally by doing the "release" build instead of a debug build, and I get the following error:

`apple pay error This device can make payments but has no supported cards`

This is on the same same phone that works fine with a debug build. So, I'm assuming this is just a bad error message. I'm pretty certain it has something to do with the debug vs release cert, but I can't find anywhere that those are set independently.

Additional notes:

- In the apple developer portal apple pay is enabled for both "development" and "distribution".
- Under capabilities in xcode apple pay is on, the merchant id is correct, and all the "steps" are checked. There doesn't appear to be build specific settings

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I have NO IDEA where (or if) this is in the Xcode ui, but in the root of the project there are 2 files `Entitlements-Debug.plist` and `Entitlements-Release.plist`.

The following appeared in the debug one, but not the release:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.in-app-payments</key>
<array>
  <string>merchant.myapp-here.com</string>
</array>
```

Feels like this is something Xcode should do automatically, but copying these lines to the release plist fixed the issue.